# Having direct user input in java

Tags: java

I apologize for how I asked my previous question but hope that I can make this question clearer. I am trying to write a code where a user can place information under the columns of firstname, lastname and marks but I have failed.
With this code I have written the values under num are supposed to be automatic.

Please help me out and thank you.

```
package school;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Assign1 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("NUM\t FIRSTNAME \t LASTNAME \t MARKS \t GRADE");

      int i=1;
      String f = sc.nextLine();
      while(i<=2) {
        System.out.print(i+ "\t");
        System.out.print("\t" + f);
        i++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking how you can parse the entered String and extract the information like lastname and grade to own variables?

Comment: I also don't quite understand the question. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: The question needs to be more clear. Please provide example of expected output and what you are getting currently. It looks like you are trying to produce some kind of table with headers NUM FIRSTNAME LASTNAME MARKS GRADE followed by user inputed values.Take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples for examples of formatting strings.

Comment: Yes.. exactly what @Bradley is saying is what i am trying to do.

Comment: to create a table with the headings of NUM,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME MARKS GRADE  that allows access to user input for FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME MARKS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You want the mentioned columns to be printed and the user to input data under each column. You also want the number column to print numbers automatically. Here is the code for that program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Assign1 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("NUM\t FIRSTNAME\t LASTNAME\t MARKS\t GRADE");

    int i=1;

    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    int marks = 0;
    String grade = "";

    while(i<=2) {
        System.out.print(i+ "\t ");
        firstName = sc.next();
        lastName = sc.next();
        marks = sc.nextInt();
        grade = sc.next();
        i++;
    }

 }
}
```

To store each kind of column data, we need different variables of the proper type. Next, we are inputting data from the user while staying inside the loop. Since `i=1`, the while condition is `true` 2 times and the user is able to enter 2 different records.

The output will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you @Mishra

Comment: Let me get to it and make some adjustments

Comment: question please, what is the importance of having the empty strings

Comment: That is called initializing the variables. If I had not initialized the variables and tried to print the value of firstName or any of the other variables after coming outside the while loop, it would have given me an error. But because I have initialized the variables, if I tried to access them after coming outside the loop, it would give me the last values those variables were holding (the values of the second record) and not throw an error.